# problem in installing django

Tags: python, django

problem with installing django
i am geting folllowing error

```
E:\Softwares\Django-1.1.1.tar\Django-1.1.1\Django-1.1.1>setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Softwares\Django-1.1.1.tar\Django-1.1.1\Django-1.1.1\setup.py", line
48, in ?
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Comment: And a recent version? (`__file__` wasn't available in the main script until Python 2.3.)

Comment: That version is more than seven years old. Django is only compatible with versions 2.4 upwards.

Answer (score 4):

The Python version you are using, 2.2, is more than seven years old. Django is only compatible with versions 2.4 upwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use`python setup.py install`